# Getting Logical Subexpressions Using Stack

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, logic, expression

I don't have any code right now, but I'm simply trying to process how I'm going to perform this algorithm and I just need some ideas.

Say I have the String for example:

```
((A+B)*(C+B)) * (A+C)
```

I don't want to use regex for this at all but I'm trying to figure out how to do this using strictly Stack operations. I was thinking of maybe counting the brackets but then I have to account for double inner-brackets. I'm completely lost of other ideas.

So for this String, I just want to **derive** the following:

```
A+B
C+B
(A+B)*(C+B)
A+C
((A+B)*(C+B)) * (A+C)      // The original String
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are all subexpressions always surrounded by brackets?

Comment: Nope. If it's a single expression then A+B should be fine. Other than that, they are required to be input. I just wanted to assume the worst case scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based on an assumption that every subexpression is surrounded by parenthesis (except, maybe, for the entire expression). It's a simplification of the shunting-yard algorithm, which can parse an arbitrary arithmetic expressions:

Let's keep a stack of tokens (represented as strings). The stack is initially empty. We iterate over the string and for each character, do the following:

1. If it's a closing parenthesis, keep popping tokens of the stack until an opening parenthesis is found. Concatenate all the popped tokens (including parenthesis), print the result and push it back to the stack.
2. Otherwise just push the token to the stack.

If the number of tokens on the stack is not one, we need to print the content of the stack after the algorithm is finished (it corresponds to the case when the entire expression is not parenthesized).

Here is an example of how it works:

Let the string be `((A+B)*(C+D))`.

We keep pushing tokens to the stack until the first closing parenthesis is encountered. At that point, the stack looks like `[(, (, A, +, B`]. We keep popping the tokens until we hit the `(`. After concatenating them, we get `(A+B)` and push it back to the stack. The state of the stack is `[(, (A+B)]` now. After that, we push the tokens until we reach the next `)`. The stack is `[(, (A+B), *, (, C, +, D]`. After popping, the new expression is `(C+D)` and the stack becomes `[(, (A+B), *, (C+D)]`. Finally, we reach the last `)` and pop everything off and get the entire expression.

Note: this solution assumes that the spaces are removed from the string before the input is processed.

By the way, you can't solve this problem with regular expression because the language we're dealing with in this problem is not regular.